# Is there a way to extract the WiFi protocol type from a PcapNG trace file?

Tags: python, wireshark, wifi, pcap-ng

I'm building a PcapNG parser (in Python) to analyse WiFi packets.
I'd like to be able to display the *link type* (e.g., the protocol variant: 802.11b, 802.11a, 802.11g or 802.11n).

However, reading the [PcapNG format definition](https://www.winpcap.org/ntar/draft/PCAP-DumpFileFormat.html) I see only the following being mentioned:

- LINKTYPE_IEEE802_11  105 IEEE 802.11 (wireless)
- LINKTYPE_IEEE802_11_RADIO    127 802.11 plus BSD radio header

**Is there a way to extract the WiFi protocol type from a PcapNG trace file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the link-layer header type for the interface on which the packet was captured is LINKTYPE_IEEE802_11, no, you can't get the protocol variant.

If the link-layer header type for the interface on which the packet was captured is LINKTYPE_IEEE802_11_RADIOTAP (yes, that's the correct name; the list of link-layer header types in the wiretap.org pcap-NG spec is out of date, the up-to-date list is [the tcpdump.org Link-Layer Header Types page](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html)), then the packet begins with a [radiotap header](http://www.radiotap.org) giving various meta-data about the packet.

If the radiotap header includes the [Channel](http://www.radiotap.org/defined-fields/Channel) field, then, from the information there, you can determine some information about the protocol variant:

- "5 GHz spectrum channel" + "OFDM channel" = 802.11a;
- "2 GHz spectrum channel" + "CCK channel" = 802.11b;
- "2 GHz spectrum channel" + "OFDM channel" = 802.11g;
- "2 GHz spectrum channel" + "Dynamic CCK-OFDM channel" = 802.11g;

(the difference between the two flavors of 802.11g indicates whether there might also be 802.11b traffic on the same channel - that's what the "Dynamic CCK-OFDM channel" indicates).

*However*, if the [MCS](http://www.radiotap.org/defined-fields/MCS) field is present, it's 802.11n, not any of those other types, and if the [VHT](http://www.radiotap.org/defined-fields/VHT) field is present, it's 802.11ac.

There might also be an [XChannel](http://www.radiotap.org/suggested-fields/XChannel) field, which can be interpreted similarly to the Channel field, although it also contains some information for 802.11n.